# My friend lost the ability to ask questions. Is there any way he can get the ability back?

Tags: support, asking

My friend lost the ability to ask questions, due to his first questions having negative reputation. Since then he has gained more reputation due to helpful answers.

The message he got told him to wait one day, but he has and he still cannot ask questions.

Is there a way for him to ask questions again?

Comment: I see that you have already found several helpful answers to your problem. Please click the green check button next to the answer you found most helpful, so that others know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing [this is your friend](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/136645/nucleartiger52)?

They posted and then deleted several questions. This type of behaviour is a pain, and can be a sign of spamming. The ban is automatic, and cannot be manually lifted. It will expire only once you've earned enough positive reputation to demonstrate your ability to post constructively. It is *not* a timed ban and it will not expire.

If your friend would like their deleted question undeleted so that they can fix them, I can do that, just leave a comment here.

If the same behaviour happens again and the auto-ban kicks in again it will be even longer, so take some time to properly research your question and make it a good one!

There are some [help centre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) articles that can help!

Comment: thank you for your help, can you tell me how much reputation is required to lift the ban?

Comment: @Sparta270 - Note that fredley probably doesn't know specifics, only the general rule. If you're asking specifically so your friend (or you) can ask for/farm upvotes, that *isn't* the way to go about it. Rep is something that will be earned *organically* through quality content, not through people 'upvoting to lift the ban'. :) There's also a bot that looks at suspicious upvote patterns (such as two friends upvoting each other constantly) :)

Comment: I can't tell you, because I don't know! It also may be proportional to how much you annoyed the ban bot in the first place.

Comment: i aint' trying to farm it, just wanted to know about the general amount. Thanks.s for the help guy

Comment: @Sparta270 - just making sure :-). It's happened before is all.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [help center for question bans](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans), question bans are added automatically by the system and removed by the system, so it's not something that can be manually lifted for a specific user. That user will need to contribute positively, starting with fixing their existing questions.

However, the error message for a question ban doesn't mention any sort of time limit, so your friend may be running into our [question rate limiter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited) instead. This ban is temporary and will automatically resolve itself. With that said, the intention of the rate limiter is to slow the user down so that they have time to fix their existing questions before they end up with a full question ban.

We also might be able to provide advice how the user can specifically fix those early questions if you provide links to them.

Comment: thanks for the help.